# Obfuscator for algorithms in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, obfuscation

I want to protect some algorithms, from being reversed engineered. I know there is always a risk, but I want to make the work as complicated as possible. I know in Java there are ProGuard and other obfuscator. But the most knowledge isn't in the structure of the application, but in the numerical details of the algorithm. And reading about it, made me doubt on the protection of the algorithm.

Simple renaming some variables, wouldn't make it hard enough to reverse engineer the algorithms. Perhaps you can tell me, which methods would be more appropriate for algorithms and which of obfuscator may do the best work on algorithms.

At the moment I'm thinking about a bit handwork and to combine it with a tool.

Comment: If your algorithm is that important, don't give an implementation of it to anyone else. Run it only on hardware that *you* control and sell it as a service. Everything else is going to be reverse-engineered.

Comment: Can the numbers be stored in an encrypted or obfuscated way?

Comment: Maybe you can translate the specific algo as a c/c++ dll and call it with JNI? Much harder to reverseengineer

Comment: If the software is given to another machine, then it's out of your control; someone could very easily reverse engineer it.  It's a risk you take with algorithms in software.

Comment: funny i have read that very same question somewhere else before. Would it make sense to offer your computation "as a service" and not give out the code/binary at all? That's the only way you can be sure...

Comment: "numerical details of the algorithm"? I hope you are not trying to hide a private cryptographic key in your program. You can make this more difficult with security by obscurity, but you won't be able to prevent it when someone really tries.

Comment: The algorithms should be used in an product. We have to put it on the device, because we can't make the product require the internet.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I can't tell it yet. I'm not the author of the algorithm. But I can check it, if the author is handing it over to implement the algorithm in the product. If can give me a good resource about it I would be thankful.

Comment: @Philipp No, its really a algorithm with numerical knowlege in a special domain. I don't think a whole team will work on the reverse engineering of the algorithms. But to some people this could be very interesting- We want to make it as hard as possible, but a rest risk is OK.

Comment: @Rolle We want to go with Java, because its deployed to several system architectures, with different instruction sets. And we don't want to get problems we can't predict, because of the native code.

Comment: I think if you can't require the internet and a hardware solution is viable, then doing that will probably raise the clue barrier to a pretty high level. I think there are *a lot more* people that can reverse-engineer well-obfuscated software than there are people who can reverse-engineer a custom chip (or even an FPGA).

Comment: @Sauer A hardware solution is in the productionsize of the product not profitable. I think a well-obfuscated software, will make the hurdle high enough in the domain. The domain isn't this huge. We just don't want to make it too easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your algorithm should be executed as Java bytecode, on arbitrary JVMs. Then people can hack their JVM to dump the bytecode somewhere, no matter how much you obfuscate the class loading process. Once you have the bytecode, you can do control flow analysis, i.e. decide what information gets passed from where to where.

You can confuse the order of the individual instructions, but that won't change the computation. For someone who simply wants to run your algorithm unmodified, this doesn't change anything. How much a reordering will prevent people from modifying your algorithm very much depends on the algorithm and the complexity of the control flow.

You might be able to confuse the control flow using reflection in some obscure way, or by implementing your own interpreter and using that to run the algorithm. But both these approaches will likely come at a severe penalty to the performance of the algorithm.

In other languages (like native x86 code) you might be able to confuse the disassembler by introducing ambiguity about how the bytes should be split into instructions, using some bytes as tail part of an instruction in one case, but as a distinct instruction in other cases. But in Java there is no such option, the meaning of bytecode is too well defined.

One way you *might* be able to obfuscate things somewhat is by closely intermixing the algorithm with other steps of the program. For a straight-line program, this might make things a wee bit harder to track, in particular if you pass numbers through invisible GUI objects or similar bizarre stuff. But once you require loops or similar, getting the loop bounds lined up seems very hard, so I doubt that this approach has much potential either. And I doubt there is a ready-to-use obfuscator for this, so you'd have to do things by hand.

Comment: I think even the possibilities of obfuscating code in native assembler aren't much of a problem for a determined attacker (for example look at the rate at which DRM systems for games are broken).

Comment: Native Code is out for us. 
Ok, I see best way to obfuscuate the code is per Hand. Its not about using the algorithm, its more about understanding the algorithm. Thx for your tips.

Comment: @GiCo While obfuscating the code by hand is a suitable alternative, I am little bit puzzled by what you mean with numerical details. If you are referring to some constants you should try to avoid hardcoded numbers (e.g., store the numbers in byte arrays and convert them when necessary).

Comment: I mean numerics as a mathematic disipline, not numbers. I'm not sure if my english was correct. But the project is finished.

Answer (score 1):

In my exeperience you can use .so file I.e. native implementation with java implementation and it is really hard to track with obfsucated code but only disadvantage is you will have to use JNI for that.

Comment: Actualy, we want to get away from native code, because we aren't sure we can handle the different Systemarchitectures. We are search for a way to do a good obfuscation, raising the work perhaps to one Month of work. I think this will be a high enough hurdle, because the people couldn't really use it without our knowlege and so the benefit isn't so big. It's a small domain, everyone works with nearly everybody.